# Fetching final rows based on the column of resulted rows when another column is matched

Tags: mysql, sql, join

**Example**
**Table 1** 
**id**  **table3_fk**

```
1  -101

2  -103

3  -104

4  -101 
5  -105
```

------------------------ 

**Table 2**

id(same as table 1) table4_fk 
1                     -1001   
2                     -1003   
3                     -1001   
4                     -1002   
5                     -1001   
*****************************

If I join Table 1 and Table 2 based on the id then resulted rows will be some number , but I want to have all resulted rows from table 2 based on the table4_fk after I do first join 

**lets say :**

select * from Table1 as t1  join Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
where t1.table3_fk = -101

result will be :

**id** **table4_fk**  **table3_fk** 
1   -1001     -101  
4   -1002     -101  
Query : Needed -------------------

-------------------------------------------------
Needed result is:(look at table4_fk column after match) 

**id**              **table4_fk**  **table3_fk** 
1                     -1001          -101     
3                     -1001          -104   
4                     -1002          -101   
5                     -1001          -105    
--------------------------------------------------------

Please put forward your ides interms of any sql query knowledge.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Select x.* from your table x join (your query here) y on y.table4fk = x.table4fk

Answer (score 0):

```
 select * from Table1 as t1  join Table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
where t1.table3_fk <> -103
```

Try this code

Comment: I doubt that this is what the OP wants, but based upon the paucity of the information provided in the question, the solution would seem valid.

Comment: Basically i only know about -101 id (which is one at a time)

Comment: Please dont consider that id is known... please give me generalised solution.

Comment: Please consider all id are generated only i know is supplied id that is -101(or anything)

Answer (score -1):

This query should work as expected:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.table4_fk, t1.table3_fk 
FROM Table1 AS t1  
     JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE t1.table3_fk <> '-103'
```

Output:

id table4_fk table3_fk

1   -1001   -101

3   -1001   -104

4   -1002   -101

5   -1001   -105

Comment: This isn't what the op wants, hence their reference to table4fk

Comment: @Strawberry Oops, got the table structure wrong. Can you share the correct query?

Comment: When you downvote an answer, please be fair and explain.

Comment: See comments above (although it could just as well be written without a subquery)

Comment: Please consider all id are generated only i know is supplied id that is -101(or anything)